# Grub Menu doesn't appear when pressing SHIFT

Tags: grub2

I'd like to access my Grub Menu at boot by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>.
After I press <kbd>Shift</kbd> I see a message saying "Grub loading.."
but then no menu appears and the computer keeps booting normally
into my Ubuntu Installation.
Do you know how I can access the Grub Menu at boot?
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I fiugred that out, the value GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT in the file /etc/default/grub has to be set to a value greater than 0.

Comment: If this solves your problem, you can answer your own question with this information and mark it as correct. Then other users will see this question is answered.

Comment: I can do that only after 8 hrs... Will do it tomorrow..

Comment: Sounds good. A lot of users never update their questions. Glad you solved your problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue is solved by modifying the parameter `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` in the `/etc/default/grub` file (need to be super user to modify it), and (as always to apply configuration changes made in this file) running `sudo update-grub`.

Changing the value from 0 to some positive value allows to enter the GRUB menu by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> during boot.

For those not familiar with updating your GRUB settings:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal.
2. Run `gksu gedit /etc/default/grub`.
3. Change the `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` line as above, save it, and close gedit.
4. Run `sudo update-grub`.  You can now restart.

---

If you want from the GUI

To open the terminal:

Open Dash (Super Key) or Applications and type `terminal`

[image]

For older or Ubuntu versions:

Applications -> Accessories -> Terminal

Then type the command `gksu gedit /etc/default/grub`

and then change the value in `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` as above.

[image]

Save it and close the editor.

and run `sudo update-grub` in the terminal.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This finally worked for me :

1. Goto your BOOT menu and then go to BOOT settings - change "BOOT MODE" to "Legacy" from "UEFI" --> Save
2. Shut Down and restart.
3. In my case, it showed "No operating system found"
4. Quick shut down your system(by pressing the power button continuously for 15 secs)
5. Goto the Boot menu again and reverse the Boot mode back to UEFI.
6. Restart your System. This time most probably the GRUB menu will appear.