# Linux not booting up due to 2 graphic drivers installed. How do I switch to the original one without the machine being started/ booted?

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, lubuntu, gpu-driver

I tried installing litrus on my Linux machine which originally is a Windows one, Dell Precision 7760. Prompted new graphic install and then it does not start after booting up. I can access the Grub GNU before the boot is initiated. The Litrus installer asked for a graphic driver installation which I ran on my terminal which asked me to reboot the machine. Can I retrieve my data without booting the machine? The laptop screen starts blinking after the Command on the blank screen:
Finished wait until snapd is fully seeded.

Comment: Before booting the laptop*

Comment: You've provided no release details (ie. given clues as to what software stack you're using, release details are very useful in this regard). You can boot your system using *live* media allowing you to access your files, and **without booting your installed system**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to start Ubuntu in Console mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/859630/how-to-start-ubuntu-in-console-mode)

Answer (score 1):

You can not have 2 graphics drivers installed on a (L)ubuntu system.

> Can I retrieve my data without booting the machine?

Yes.

3 ways. Easiest first, the risky one last:

- That is what the live session dvd/usb is for that you used to install Lubuntu with. Boot from it, copy all files to another usb stick, external hard disk, or a cloud storage. And then attempt to fix your boot. The 2nd option might be possible:
- It is possible from grub rescue to reset the graphics card. See https://askubuntu.com/a/272445/15811 and/or [Need to deactivate NVIDIA driver from recovery mode or using Ubuntu 12.04 install disk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/352093/need-to-deactivate-nvidia-driver-from-recovery-mode-or-using-ubuntu-12-04-instal)
- You can also reinstall without formatting your system; that will also keep your personal files. But 1 mistake at the installation process will be fatal.